# How to automatically run a query when a table is amended by INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers, synchronization

I have a query which basically "syncs" all the data from a table in one database, to a replicated table in another database.

Here is the simple query:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [Database2].[dbo].[USER_SYNC]

INSERT INTO [Database2].[dbo].[USER_SYNC]
SELECT * FROM [Database1].[dbo].[USER]
```

Now, after some research, I had a look into using a **trigger** to do this, however, I read up that stored procedures and heavy queries such as this should not be used within a trigger.

Therefore, what is the best way in which I can automatically run this query from within SQL, whenever a record in **database1** is inserted, amended or deleted?

And if what I read up about triggers was incorrect, then how would I go about creating one for my procedure? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to sync tables you do not need to truncate one every time on update, delete or insert.

1. Create identical copy of user table.
2. Create on update, on delete, on insert triggers on the original user table.
3. In the trigger update, delete or insert to the duplicate table only one row at a time - the one that was updated, deleted or inserted to the original user table. This will not be a heavy query.

UPDATE:

- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Ah yes, of course, I don't know why I didn't think of that at first. It seems quite straight forward. Will now do further research on how to create such triggers and put it to test. Thank you for your response.